# Using enter to submit a content in a textarea via ajax in rails3.1rc5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have rails app with a textarea form like

```
<%= form_for Comment.new, :remote => true do |f| %>
<%= f.text_area :comment %>
<% end %>
```

and my javascript code is as follows

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('textarea').keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var frm = this.form.submit();
            $.ajax({
                url: frm.attr(),
                data: frm.serialize(),
                success: {},
                dataType: json
            });
        }
    });

});

</script>
```

the problem here is that the form gets submitted when the enter key is triggered but it does not render an ajax request instead the form is submitted via http request. Any help here thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need both to submit form and send ajax request, you should submit from after ajax request has been executed. So, you shoud either make ajax request syncronous or submit for in the ajax callback function.

If you don't need form to be submitted, use this

```
var frm=$(this).parent(); //if textarea tag directly in the from tag
```

because this code `this.form.submit();` submits the form.

**UPD**

```
    $(function(){
        $('textarea').keypress(function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
                e.preventDefault();
//                var frm = this.form.submit(); <- this code submits the form immediately
                  var frm = $(this).parent(); // depends on form structute
                $.ajax({
                    url: frm.attr('action'),
                    data: frm.serialize(),
                    complete: function(){
                        frm.submit(); // if you need to submit form after ajax request has been completed, I think it is useless
                    },
                    dataType: json
                });
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: Thanks you. But i am no javascript expert a brief example from my code structure would be nice. Thanks

Comment: tried it out but the comment does not get posted and no request is ocuring on my server. what am i getting wrong

Answer (score 1):

1) You're submitting the form yourself, so it's no wonder it gets submitted

2) Your `frm` variable is incorrect, I think. You're setting it the the returned value of submit (which you shouldn't call anyway).

Try

```
$(function(){
    $('textarea').keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var frm = this.form; // don't submit the form yet
            $.ajax({
                url: $(frm).attr('action'), // remember to specify which attribute you want
                data: $(frm).serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function() { frm.submit(); } // submit the form when the ajax request is complete
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5yQjA/
The fiddle logs the various things that should occur in an element below the textarea, but that's just for testing - remove it in your version. Also, remember to uncomment the `frm.submit()` line

Comment: Thank you. But i have tried it out but this time the form does not get submitted

Comment: @Uchenna Okafor: My mistake - I thought you _didn't_ want the form submitted; only the ajax. I'll update my answer

Comment: tried it out but the comment does not get posted and no request is occurring on my server. what am i getting wrong

Comment: for more clarity i would use the facebook feeds comment area as an example.

Comment: one more observation the url is not making any request could it be because of the ('action')

Comment: @UchennaOkafor: Well, I don't use Facebook, so... :)   Anyway, there was a bug in the code: "json" should be in quotes. I've updated my answer and added a link to a jsfiddle example. As for the `('action')` part, I'm assuming you want to send the data to the url specified in the form element. Lastly: I'd advice you to use Firebug or the Chrome/Safari developer console to see if there are any javascript errors that prevent it from working